# Icecast streamming not playing

Tags: android, audio-streaming, icecast

I am creating app to send audio to icecast server. Here I connected to icecast server and sending the audio data to server. But Streaming seen on server, but it is not playing in browser Why?

Is there need to encode that data to any format?

Comment: Take a packet capture so we can see what you've actually done thus far.  It's impossible to help you debug this with no information.

Comment: @Brad I have no idea about packet capturing.I just created a code which connect to icecast server and  i seen mount point is set and streaming is showing in browser.But is is not playing until i stop the sending audio data.when i stop sending audio data then it try to play but it not playing.The problem is not in media player actually i want to ask that is there need to encode that data to mp3 or oggg.

Comment: You need to pick a codec that the browser supports.

Comment: I played that file and following error shows in media player classic.

Comment: File Source (Async.)::Output
Media Type 0:
--------------------------
Unknown
AM_MEDIA_TYPE: 
majortype: MEDIATYPE_Stream {E436EB83-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}
subtype: MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG1Audio {E436EB87-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}
formattype: TIME_FORMAT_NONE {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
bFixedSizeSamples: 1
bTemporalCompression: 0
lSampleSize: 1
cbFormat: 0

Comment: @brad i search on net that before sending the stream they are encoding in the mp3 format or ogg format in code, is it necessary to encode data or just send the raw audio data.                    
 
and thanks for your reply.

Comment: You must encode the data.  You cannot send raw PCM samples.  You will want to do the encoding on the mobile device to save bandwidth.  You must do this encoding before sending the data to the Icecast server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Now am encoding the data by using lame library.I seen the tutorial which encode files but not stream and here we want to encode stream,Do any know any better tutorials for that.And really am very thankful for your reply Brad.

Comment: LAME on Android?  It depends on which LAME package you are using.  Did you compile it yourself, or are you using one of the existing services to do it?  I don't know of any tutorials.  I was writing similar software awhile back, but never finished it because it was a huge hassle to get LAME or FFMPEG functioning on Android.

Comment: I am following this type of tutorial http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Porting-and-using-LAME-MP3-on-Android-with-JNI   ,using ndk.Actually i want the format ogg and vorbis but for the  simplicity am using lame library.Thanks for your all comments.I seen lots of answer give by you for icecast development,you are so active user thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i am sending the audio PCM data to server.Now i encoded that PCM data to ogg format to send on server.Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems with a web-based player you need to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to do and provide some code for us to look at.

You should also confirm the stream is playing correctly in a compatible desktop app first.

Go to `http://example.com:8000/admin` and verify the mount point you're sending to is listed (which indicates it has a connected source) - if it is there will be an [M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) (for streaming MP3) and [XSPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xspf) (for Ogg) link on the right which you can use to test.

Playback of Icecast streams on Android requires installation of the [Just Playlists](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.journeyman.android.apps.justplaylists&hl=en) app or an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the audio encoding. Set encoding data as follows

Capture device inputs

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Set input from device or other protocol.
Example:

```
ffplay -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (FaceCam 1000X)"
```

Then stream

```
ffmpeg -stats -report -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (FaceCam 1000X)" -c:a flac -compression_level 10 -ar 192000 -legacy_icecast 1 -content_type application/ogg -ice_name "Optional Name" -f ogg icecast://source:password_for_streaming@127.0.0.1:8000/live.ogg
```